# Spring boot rest security with android and ios

Tags: android, ios, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing **spring rest webservice** and my clients are **android** and **ios** applications. The problem is my application is **100% api based** there is no website even for the admin, everything is mobile and I have been struggling how to do **authentication and authorization** with just apis. I did small spring projects before where my client was the browser. But now I have been stuck for a week and I can't seem to find anything on how to do this authentication and authorization thing. Is it my approach or is it so unusual thing. I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look into OAuth2: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Basic Authentication or Digest Authentication

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html

But you should be careful and do not use it with HTTP, only with HTTPS, since basic authentication transmits the password as plain text.

Second way is to use JWT for securing your application. Here is example of using JWT https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo